# How do I make Windows 10 log off the current user when another user logs in?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, login

I'm running Windows 10 Education on a Windows domain, and I'm running into problems with computers running out of resources because some people don't log out. Some of the worst machines have 10-15 people logged in at any one time.

I'd like to make it so when a user logs in, any currently logged-in user is automatically and forcibly disconnected. I suppose I could make a batch script that runs at logon and disconnects other users, but I was hoping there was a GPO or something I have missed that will handle this more elegant.

I realize this should be fixed with user training but I'm in public education and have over 1000 users, many of which are completely apathetic if not outright hostile.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hmm, wasn't there a GPO for inactive session timeout?

Comment: The inactive session timeout just locks the computer, which will cause the same issue. I did look into it but I don't think I can chain anything else off the inactivity timer, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

What about a workaround?

Disable fast user switching as described in this article:
https://www.technipages.com/windows-10-enable-or-disable-fast-user-switching

Then just set the computers to never lock so users don't have the option to log in to a computer with multiple users.

Another option I came across (paid) while searching is something called "Goverlan"

Comment: While this is a novel solution that would technically work, making it easy to use someone else's profile is my nightmare situation. I would much rather keep training people to reboot particularly slow computers than allow a user to send death threats to another user from a third user's account, for example.

Goverlan looks like it would work but do way more than I would need. I'd be doubling on some software that I already use and paying for one tiny piece of software. It is very cool, though, thanks for making me aware of it!